# MySQL, filtering but counting for different values

Tags: mysql, filter, count

I'm writing a simple football database, and in that database, I want teams are played in UEFA but count the number of wins in the UEFA.

Teams can play UEFA and results should be 'win' 'draw' or 'lose'

To do that, I wrote this query but I do not know how should I change the count statement, because this query gives the number of matches for each team that is played in UEFA.

```
SELECT t.name, count(*) as Wins
FROM Teams t, Matches m
WHERE competion = 'UEFA' AND t.name = m.team
GROUP BY t.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the appropriate criteria, it will look something like:

```
SELECT t.name, count(*) as matches,
sum(case when result = "win" then 1 else 0 end) as wins,
sum(case when result = "draw" then 1 else 0 end) as draws,
sum(case when result = "loss" then 1 else 0 end) as losses
FROM Teams t, Matches m
WHERE competion = 'UEFA' AND t.name = m.team
GROUP BY t.name
```

Comment: I got You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sum(case when result = 'win' then 1 else 0 end) as wins,
 sum(case when result = ' at line 2

Comment: Yes I got it, there is a comma needed at the end of the first line